# custom tool error consume webService

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio

I'm trying to consume a webservice from a 3'rd party phone provider, the customTool from visual studio gives me errors.

I searched a lot and tried all solutions provided, but still not luck with it)

[Thats the url to the service](https://webserv.telebroad.com/api/v11/index.php?wsdl)

The error is:

```
Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:TelebroadWebServices']/wsdl:portType[@name='TelebroadWebServicesPortType']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='urn:TelebroadWebServices']/wsdl:binding[@name='TelebroadWebServicesBinding']    ....\Reference.svcmap
```

**Update:**
I tried to generate the .net classes using soapUI, I get the following error:

```
Running .NET wsdl.exe
directory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin
command: [cmd.exe, /C, wsdl.exe, /nologo, /verbose, /namespace:Telebroad, /out:C:\TempPc, /protocol:SOAP, /language:VB, https://webserv.telebroad.com/api/v11/index.php?wsdl]
Warning: This web reference does not conform to WS-I Basic Profile v1.1.
R2706: A wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST use the value of "literal" for the use attribute in all soapbind:body, soapbind:fault, soapbind:header and soapbind:headerfault elements.
```

....

```
If you would like more help, please type "wsdl /?".
Error: Unable to import binding 'TelebroadWebServicesBinding' from namespace 'urn:TelebroadWebServices'.
  - Unable to import operation 'get_call_history'.
  - The datatype 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/:call_history_item' is missing.
```

Comment: I just imported the WSDL into SOAP UI and can see all the requests.

Comment: No I did not use Visual Studio. SOAP UI is a standalone product however if SOAP UI can import it I cant see anything wrong with the WSDL it looks good.

Comment: But the fact is that visual studio does have a problem with it... if you don't see a problem, maybe some other friends here could see. I tried with VS2008, VS2012, VS2013 and it does not work.

Comment: Why vote to close? I asked a valid question that is very clear.

Comment: I copy and pasted the WSDL into XML Spy and Liquid XML and it is valid. So all I can point you to is that the WSDL is working and is valid. Sorry cannot help much more I dont have Visual Studio at the office.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted the developer of that script, and they were able to modify the wdsl in a way the item should be visible in the wsdl file.

I'm sharing that info here for others that read my question, if you tried all other fixes and still no luck, then just send an email to the owner of the webService, they should be able to fix it for you...